# How do I use a custom AVI with TAnimate?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have an AVI file that I pulled from shell32 using [Resources Extract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html). I would like to use this with TAnimate but I can't figure out how to load this file.

I succesfully loaded the AVI into a .RES file using [DelphiDabbler's rcdatacreator program](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=2) (you have to download the "worked example" to get rcdatacreator. However, my issue now is figuring out how to extract the AVI file from the .RES and supplying it to TAnimate.

I am  using Delphi 2010:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Procedure described ought to be a license violation. Read about `ResHandle`.

Comment: That's a good point, it could be a license violation if I distribute this AVI (taken from shell32). I will begin looking elsewhere for a more open-source animation.

Comment: Why? Animate controls can play resources from any loaded module since Windows 5.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Andreas mentioned (in his now deleted answer), you don't need to use an external tool to add the resource in recent versions of Delphi.

Use `Project/Resources and Images...` from the IDE menu. Add a new resource by browsing to the folder your .AVI file is in, give it a name, and type in `AVI` for the Resource Type. (It's not in the list, but you can add it.)

[image: Delphi Resources Editor]

At runtime, use the following code:

```
// I used CoolAVI as the resource name in my image above,
// so that's the name I need to use here.
Animate1.ResName := 'COOLAVI';
Animate1.Active := True;
```

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. I tried to get you to change your answer instead. :)

Comment: I don't have "AVI" as a resource type in Delphi 2010. Is there a way to add that another way?

Comment: Unfortunately, in my Delphi 2010 project I could not modify the type using the IDE. However, opening up the DPROJ file and manually setting the type to AVI worked.

Comment: @KenWhite I tried it with `cool.avi` and it works fine. Then I tried it with an other animation file `websend.avi` (of course gave it an other resource id name: WEBSENDAVI) which crashed the program with an error message: "Cannot open AVI.". So it seems this works only with certain types of AVI files. Which AVI file type is supposed to work in this way with TAnimate?

Comment: @user1580348: According to the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Animation_Control), "uncompressed AVI files or AVI clips compressed using run-length encoding". I don't know anything about `websend.avi`, so I can't help there. We use a couple of non-standard AVIs this way without any issues.