# websend.avi as a custom resource for TAnimate?

Tags: delphi, animation, delphi-xe2, avi

In Delphi XE2, I try to use `websend.avi` as a custom resource for TAnimate, by including it in `Project/Resources and Images`, in the same way as referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374684/how-do-i-use-a-custom-avi-with-tanimate):

[image]

```
Animate1.ResName := 'WEBSENDAVI';
Animate1.Active := True;
```

However, while the same procedure works fine with `cool.avi`, it always crashes with `websend.avi`:

[image]

So it seems TAnimate can accept only certain AVI files, while it crashes with other AVI files.
Which are the rules for AVI files to work with TAnimate in the above way?

Comment: What codecs do the two files use? Check this with GSpot.

Comment: websend.avi uses CRAM-Microsoft Video 1, 
cool.avi uses (_RGB)-BI_RGB Raw Bitmap

Comment: better trace error in the sources of `TAnimate` component. The same message would pop up due to ANY error, even when it just cannot find the resource. So you better trace execution down to the reason of the error.

Comment: AviDemux or VirtualDub may unpack the video

Comment: JFTR, TAnimate is the lightest of lightweight AVI players... I wouldn't count on for much more than the "standard" windows AVI's for file transfer, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Animation_Control) explains that you can use AVI files with raw uncompressed frames, or with run length encoding compression. The AVI of yours that fails does not meet those requirements.

Comment: And they must, IIRC, be soundless.

Comment: Thanks! Now I've used VirtualDub to convert websend.avi to RLE codec. Now it works with TAnimate! However the file size went from 48.6 KB to 343KB!

Comment: @user1580348 you may try GIF or some flavor of animated PNG (aPNG or MNG) but you would have to find different components for it.